# Ways to speed up python list operations

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a small python program that goes through a big text file (5Mil+ lines) line by line, extracts a single word from each line if it satisfies a condition, then appends the word to a list if it's not already there. After that I have a huge list, that I need to sort alphabetically and then write the items in the list into a new text file.

The code looks like this:

```
big_list = []
with open('big_text_file.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    for line in  f:
        # some validation specific to line structure:
        if line[0] not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0) and '\t' in line:
            word = line.rsplit('\t')[0].lower()
            if word not in big_list:
                big_list.append(word)
sorted_list = sorted(big_list)
with open('results_file.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as r:
    for item in sorted_list:
        r.write(item + "\n")
```

The trouble is it's very slow. With 5 million lines, it's been running 12+ hours now (!) and is still far from completion. I must be doing something wrong. I have a CPU with 8 cores, but in this situation only one is used. CPU load is only 12%. Can I apply multiprocessing to speed it up? Or because of the simplicity of this code, it won't be of much use? I still have to validate all words against one list.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: One obvious improvement would be to use a set, rather than a list, where you collect unique items. You can test a set for existing members in `O(1)`, but it's `O(n)` for the list.

Comment: `if line[0] not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0)` that's not what you want you want `if not line[0].isdigit()`. `line[0]` is a char, not an integer

Comment: These two suggestions should dramatically speed up your code. The second means that, currently, every line with a tab in it adds a word to the list. The second means that for every added word, you have to perform one extra operation for all future words. Your runtime is `O(n^2)` and can easily become `O(k << n)`. (Here, `k` is the number of lines matching your *intended* condition.)

Comment: Jean-François Fabre, yes! That's a bad one, thanks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Using a set (even without a set comprehension) reduced the running time from "infinity" to just 36 seconds!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentionned in comments, the main bottleneck here is the usage of a `list`.

Aside: `if line[0] not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0)` is slow and doesn't work: `line[0]` is a *char*, not and integer. Use `isdigit()` for that.

Declaring `big_list` as a `set()`, you could replace:

```
if word not in big_list:
    big_list.append(word)
```

by just

```
big_list.add(word)
```

(`word` would be added only if not already in the `set`, and check is very fast compared to `O(n)` for a `list` because it uses hashing)

Better: you can rewrite your code (the first part, and even the sort part) using a set comprehension in one line:

```
with open('big_text_file.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    big_list = sorted({line[:line.find('\t')].lower() for line in f if not line[0].isdigit() and '\t' in line})
```

Note the better way to get the first part of the line which avoids splitting (and generating a list that you almost don't use)

As said above, no need to test `in` for a `set`: if the word is already in it, it won't be inserted again, and test for insertion decision is designed to be fast.

Note that multiprocessing *could* help, but you would hit disk I/O bottleneck and the algorithm would be more complicated because you would have to "split" your big file by skipping to 8 equal parts of line numbers, create the sets, and intersect them... Let's stick to the monoprocessing part and see how it goes.

Comment: or even `line[0:line.find('\t')]` instead of `line.rsplit('\t')[0]`

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, even better, doesn't generate a list at all! edited.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `rfind` as equivalent to `rsplit`? Results are different if there are more than one tab character in the line.

Comment: @user1016274 I don't think so, because `rsplit` and `split` act the same when there's no `maxcount`. I don't know how OP got the idea of using `rsplit`

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre Correct for `split()` and `rsplit()`. But still, the `[r]find()` in your code does behave differently if there is more than one tab.

Comment: if you checking whether an element is in a big list, just convert big list to set and then check. your code will be 78 times faster.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I'm stating in my answer, you're right. 78 times is just an estimation :) it depends on the size of the list.

Answer (score 1):

In addidtion to set, I would use regular expressions to faster verify your input. This should reflect your if statements:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(?:^|\n(\s*))(?P<relevant_line>\D[^\n]*?\t[^\n]+)')
with open('big_text_file.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF8') as f:    

    matches = pattern.findall(f)

    big_set = set()

    for match in matches:
        word = match[1].split('\t')[0].lower()
        big_set.add(word)

sorted_list = sorted(big_set)
with open('results_file.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as r:
    for item in sorted_list:
        r.write(item + "\n")
```